# Equals method for sub classes of abstract class

Tags: java

I need to have a equals method for my classes which are extended from a abstract class.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public abstract class Car {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "car_seq")
private Long taskId;
}
```

and the extended class:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class ChangeTyre extends Car {

@Column(unique = true)
@NotEmpty(message = "Name must not be null or empty")
private String code;
@JoinColumn(name ="date_changed")
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate dateChanged;
@Lob
private String comment;
```

Normally a equals method would look like:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;

    if (!(o instanceof ChangeTyre))
        return false;

    ChangeTyre other = (ChangeTye) o;

    return id != null &&
            id.equals(other.getId());
}
```

But for the above code the compiler complains there is no `Id` on ChangeTyre its on the abstract class Car. How should I implement the equals method in such a case?

Comment: From the looks of `@Getter` and `@Setter`, you are already using Lombok, so use [`@EqualsAndHashCode`](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode). It has a boolean attribute called `callSuper` which you probably want

Comment: don't use the `@EqualsAndHashCode` as that generates the wrong equals / hashcode methods for jpa. Use `getTaskId` as that is the name of the property not id.

Comment: According to this i should write my own : https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-implement-equals-hashcode-and-tostring-with-jpa-and-hibernate/ but now to do this in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have named the `@Id` field `taskId`, not `id`. And the field itself is `private`, so you have to use the getter in subclasses. Update your code:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;

    if (!(o instanceof ChangeTyre))
        return false;

    ChangeTyre other = (ChangeTye) o;

    return getTaskId() != null &&
            getTaskId().equals(other.getTaskId());
}
```